# How does a process change the environment variable of its parent process?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

Take `cd` as an example. Also, it is `cd` that reminds me of this question. When we input "cd" and press enter on a terminal, a `cd` child process of the terminal starts and in my mind all things about `cd` is executed in the `cd` child process. To my puzzling, how could `cd` make it to change its parent process's environment variable?

Answer (score 4):

`cd` isn't making any changes to its parent process, because `cd` isn't a process.

It is a shell builtin - a construct that most (every?) shell has to change its directory context.

`cd` on bash will change your cwd on bash. `cd`on zsh will do the same on zsh. It is bash/zsh that are doing that. And they are changing their own context.

This being said, I don't think it's possible for a child process to change its parent's environment. It *should* be theoretically possible by directly accessing the memory, but I'm assuming we're talking about real-life scenarios :-)

Comment: But consider executing command `HOME=foo`, so this command will be executed as a child process in the current shell. So, child process just copies environment variables from parent. Why does value of `HOME` will change in the original parent shell?

Comment: @Prvt_Yadv `HOME=foo` is also not a process, but an inline update of the environment. If it precedes a command (`HOME=foo bash`), then it will set an environment variable in the child process, without affecting the current shell. If it does not precede a command (`HOME=foo` by itself), it will set a variable in the current shell, but will not affect any new child processes. If you export it (`export HOME=foo` - `export` being another shell builtin, not a process), then it will affect both the running shell and its future child processes. It still won't affect its ancestors.